# CakePHP: paginate with custom calculated field

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.x

I have 2 mysql tables as follow:

**Customers** : ID | NAME

**Customers_level** : ID | USER_ID | CUSTOMER_ID | LEVEL

I need to paginate the Customers list by name, and his average level (each user define a level for his customers). So for exemple if i have the following example :

**Customers** :

```
ID | NAME
1  | democustomer
2  | bubul
```

**Customers_level**

```
ID | USER_ID | CUSTOMER_ID | LEVEL
1  | 8       | 1           | 2
2  | 9       | 1           | 4
3  | 11      | 2           | 3
4  | 13      | 2           | 4
```

I need to have, for each customers, his avg level :

**Customer_average_level** :

```
NAME           | AVG_LEVEL
democustomer   | 3
bubul          | 3.5
```

which is possible with this sql request :

```
SELECT c.name, ROUND(AVG(ucn.note)) FROM `customers` as c, `customers_level` as ucn WHERE c.id = ucn.customer_id GROUP BY ucn.customer_id ASC
```

I'm able to sort the name, but i don't know how to add the AVG_LEVEL field available for the paginator ?
Here's my controller :

```
    $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
    $customers = $this->Paginator->paginate('Customer');
```

how can i add a virtual field on my customer paginate array list to be able to sort both on name, and on level avg ?

Comment: no help about this ?